# Rolling join + sum without blowing up memory

Tags: r, data.table

My problem's best explained with an example.

## Setup

```
library(data.table)

IDs <- 5
samplesPerId <- 100
set.seed(2019)

foo <- data.table(
  id = rep(sample(1000000, size = 5, replace = FALSE), each = samplesPerId),
  time = sample(999999, size = 5 * samplesPerId, replace = FALSE),
  val = round(runif(n = 5 * samplesPerId, min = 0, max = 1), 2)
)

setorderv(foo, c("id", "time"))
foo[, val_cmltv_max := cummax(val), by = id]
bar <- data.table(time = seq(1, 999999, by = 1))

> foo
         id   time  val val_cmltv_max
  1: 459383  11250 0.83          0.83
  2: 459383  13774 0.45          0.83
  3: 459383  22266 0.27          0.83
  4: 459383  44513 0.37          0.83
  5: 459383  49432 0.86          0.86
 ---                                 
496: 826316 950991 0.36          0.98
497: 826316 960187 0.80          0.98
498: 826316 961433 0.17          0.98
499: 826316 965398 0.36          0.98
500: 826316 994626 0.07          0.98

> bar
          time
     1:      1
     2:      2
     3:      3
     4:      4
     5:      5
    ---       
999995: 999995
999996: 999996
999997: 999997
999998: 999998
999999: 999999
```

## Goal

For each point in time, 1, 2, ... 999999, I want to get the sum of val_cmltv_max for the ids as they were known at that point in time. For example, at time 1, the sum should be 0 because no ids even existed and at time 999999 the sum should be just below 5 because there are 5 ids and by time 999999 val_cmltv_max should be near 1 for each id.

## Current Solution

Here I start with the cartesian product table of each id (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) with each time point (1, 2, ... 999999) which makes a **big** intermediate table of ~5M rows. Then, I use a rolling join to join the most recent record from foo for each id to the big intermediate table, which I then can aggregate by time taking sums of val_cmltv_max.

```
temp <- CJ(time = bar$time, id = sort(unique(foo$id)))
temp2 <- foo[temp, on = c("id", "time"), roll = TRUE]
result <- temp2[, list(sum_val_cmltv_max = sum(val_cmltv_max, na.rm = T)), by = time]

> result
          time sum_val_cmltv_max
     1:      1              0.00
     2:      2              0.00
     3:      3              0.00
     4:      4              0.00
     5:      5              0.00
    ---                         
999995: 999995              4.95
999996: 999996              4.95
999997: 999997              4.95
999998: 999998              4.95
999999: 999999              4.95
```

Is there a way to accomplish this that's fast but also memory efficient, avoiding that gigantic intermediate table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh. 5 mins after posting, I realized the solution.

```
# get the first row per unique (id, val_cmltv_max)
changes <- foo[foo[, .I[1L], by = list(id, val_cmltv_max)]$V1]

# For each id, get the change in val_cmltv_max 
# Would use shift() here but it's slow
# changes[, val_cmltv_max_prev := shift(val_cmltv_max, type = "lag", fill = 0), by = id]
changes[, val_cmltv_max_prev := c(0, head(val_cmltv_max, -1)), by = id]
changes[, change := val_cmltv_max - val_cmltv_max_prev]

# aggregate changes by time
changes <- changes[, list(change = sum(change)), by = time]

# insert into bar and cumsum
bar[, change := 0]
bar[changes, change := i.change, on = "time"]
bar[, sum_val_cmltv_max := cumsum(change)]
```